# Routing Confusion in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 app. For some reason, routing always throws me off. Currently, my RouteConfig.cs file has three routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "AddProductStep1",
  "{controller}/products/add",
  new { controller = "Core", action = "AddProduct" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
  "Products",
  "{controller}/products",
  new { controller = "Core", action = "Products" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
  "Home",
  "{controller}/dashboard",
  new { controller = "Core", action = "Dashboard" }
);
```

If I visit /core/products, I see the view associated with my products. If I visit /core/products/add, I still see the same view. I set a break point in my Controller and noticed that the Products action was getting called in both cases. That's why I believe this is a route configuration issue. Unfortunately, I don't understand what I've configured incorrectly. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: Use the route debugger. http://nuget.org/packages/routedebugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first route you have defined should probably be this instead

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "AddProductStep1",
  "{controller}/addProduct",
  new { controller = "Core", action = "AddProduct" }
);
```

The url in mvc is controller/action/param/param/etc
Your first route is looking for Core/Products/*some parameter named add*

Comment: Is there any way I can configure the routes so that I can use '/core/products/add' as a url the way I want? I really want to use that URL structure. thank you for your help!

Comment: In your case it wouldn't be about configuring the *routes* to use that url, but rather configuring the app itself.  You'd need to add products from within the Product view (with a partial maybe), and add would be a parameter passed to the Product action in the controller

Answer (score 0):

If you have the default route configured:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

When accessing `/core/products/add` you will be redirected to:

```
controller = Core
action = Products
id = Add
```

This explain the strange behaviour.